# не работает COUNT

Tags: android, sql, adapter

Мне нужно проверить есть ли в таблице значения .

**код запроса**

```
  public int getWordsCount(String language) {

    Cursor cursor_result = null;
    int count = 0;
    try {
        cursor_result = dataBase.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + MyDataBase.TABLE_WORDS + " WHERE " + MyDataBase.LANGUAGE + " = '" + language + "'");
        count = cursor_result.getCount();
        cursor_result.close();
        return count;
    } finally {
        if (cursor_result != null)
            cursor_result.close();
        return count;
    }
}
```

**код адаптера**

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    Language item = languageList.get(position);
    holder.tvLang.setText(item.getLanguage_ru());



    if (item.loading) {
        holder.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.proDown.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    } else {
        int count = ManagerDataBase.getInstance().getWordsCount(item.language);
        if (count > 0) {
            holder.tvLang.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            holder.proDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.download.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            holder.tvLang.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
            holder.proDown.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.download.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }


    }

    if (item.language.equals(lang)) {
        holder.layoutLang.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);
        holder.tvLang.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }


}
```

Моя проблема в том, что в любом случае выполняется только первая часть условия, хотя в MyDataBase.LANGUAGE передаю разные значения в адаптере для каждого элемента . 
Адаптер наследуется от `RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterPharmacy.ViewHolder>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, когда обращение к базе из адаптера перенес в отдельный поток в AsyncTask

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо не `count = cursor_result.getCount()` а прочитать значение.
Эта строчка при этом запросе всегда будет 1, т.к. результат будет:

<kbd>#</kbd><kbd>COUNT(*)</kbd> 
<kbd>1</kbd>       <kbd>?</kbd>